# Adding 3 or more Social Identity Providers for Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I want to allow users to authenticate with Google, Facebook and Microsoft Accounts along with their local account.  I'm able to add 2 social identity providers by adding one user journey to the TrustFrameworkBase and one to the TrustFrameworkExtensions.  For both of these journeys, the UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn".   Because they both have the same ID, I'm not allowed to add another UserJourney for my social identity provider.  How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple social identity providers to [the **SignUpOrSignIn** user journey](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/c05b3627a441f25cc4a28ad91ea889b8c8763de4/SocialAndLocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L1031) as follows:

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
  <ClaimsProviderSelections>
    <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange" />
    <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="GoogleExchange" />
    <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="MicrosoftAccountExchange" />
    <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
  </ClaimsProviderSelections>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>objectId</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="FacebookExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Facebook-OAUTH" />
    <ClaimsExchange Id="GoogleExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Google-OAUTH" />
    <ClaimsExchange Id="MicrosoftAccountExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="MSA-OIDC" />
    <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

For information about the **Google-OAUTH** technical profile, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-google-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga#add-a-claims-provider).

For information about the **MSA-OIDC** technical profile, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-microsoft-account-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga#add-a-claims-provider).